# Printer on Raspberry (ARMv7 architecture)

Tags: drivers, arm, printer

I'm trying to do something that might be impossible, but I'm curious.

I have a printer ([this one](https://www.primex.co.jp/NPIServlet?viewpage=4355&nextpage=4099&BLGCode=9&ModelCode=14)) that I ***need*** to be able to print images from a RaspberryPi 3b. The main problem here is that there are no drivers for ARM architecture, and using the generic ones provided by CUPS the image gets "deformed".

Using other drivers, it sometimes prints "forever" and i have to reboot the system. Nippon provides drivers but on "npi-cups-1.1.0-0.i386.rpm" format which is another architecture.

Now, I'm just learning about printers stuff, but is there any way to migrate drivers to ARM architecture, having the the ones mentioned above?

I've seen [this post](http://very%20simple%20driver%20that%20provides%20buffered%20raster%20printing%20and%20paper%20cutting%20at%20end%20of%20page%20or%20end%20of%20job.) that helped me with the EPSON TM-T70 printer, where this person makes a "very simple driver that provides buffered raster printing and paper cutting at end of page or end of job". 
Does anyone know if there is something similar for this brand (NIPPON)? In the meanwhile I'll try to reach the manufacturer in order to know if they have plans for creating drivers for ARM.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say "images", do you mean pictures as opposed to text? For text, if you just throw plain ASCII text at it, it might work. (and there's always ASCII art - JK!). Also, your link for the Epson printer is text, not a URL. If you're really desperate and are Internet connected, you might be able to send the info to another Linux computer which does have a driver for your printer and run the file through foomatic, etc. and send it back to your R Pi in native format. (I did say "really desperate".  ;)  ) Is there a user support forum/list for that or similar printers?

Comment: One more thought: if you get the driver in an rpm, you can run it through `alien` to convert it to a deb. Then, `apt` or `dpkg` would at least try to install it on Raspian. One issue is that many packages come with (pre- and) post install scripts to set things up after the base package is installed. You would have to examine those, if any, and manually translate them from the architecture they were written for to the target Raspbian. At least, they would show you what needs to be done.

Comment: The `alien` thing won't work if the package files are binary for another architecture, but might work in the less likely scenario that you can get them as source.